# Touchscreen/xinput-calibrator

Tags: touchscreen, monitor-calibration

I have been trying to install `xinput-calibrator` but when I type: `sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator`, it returns with: `Unable to locate package xinput-calibrator`.
I have tried through the software center with no luck as well. I am fairly new to this, what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `xinput-calibrator`, you must first add the ppa.

Open up a terminal by pressing and holding CTRL + ALT + T.  At which point you will enter

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tias/xinput-calibrator-ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`

At which point you can now `sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator`.